# Add border to DIV with rounded corners

Tags: html, css, border, border-radius

This seems like it wouldn't be all that hard to do, but I'm having a hard time with it.  I just want to add a left border to a div like this:

[image: DIV with rounded corners and straight left border]

I tried to add a border-left property (border-left: 5px solid blue;), but that produced this:

[image: DIV with rounded corners and rounded left border]

Can anyone tell me how to add a border with a straight edge without the rounding at the top and bottom?

Thanks!

Rob G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the parent div to hidding overflow

```css
.rounded{
  border-radius: 7px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.border{
  border-left: 6px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="rounded">
<div class="border"></div>
</div>
```